# multitasking in ios 4 later for notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications

i want to run one of my services in the background even my app is in foreground or background states,if i get any data from that service i want to show that one as a notification to the user. how can i proceed . 
as my reserach gives me an idea to follow multi taking in iphone .

or shall i use any timer so that the method calls for particular time interval for every time

```
 NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(notification) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[timer fire];

   -(void)notification
   {


       //shall i write all of my services here 

    }
```

or shall i create any new threads like

```
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(notification) withObject:Nil];
```

in `AppDelegate` file .
or shall i need to follow any other thing plz guide me thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should consider using [push notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) sent by the server to show notifications to the user when something changes. This is preferable to running in the background since it is better for system performance & battery life.

Comment: thank you for ur reply.is it this service always runs in background,could u plz provide me a good tutorial regarding this

Comment: i just have a look at this tutorial but still in confusion where to write my services which will gives me a messages http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 thank you.

Comment: what is json payload shall i have ti give the message there only,actually iam getting these messge from services menas bu using nsxml parser i just copied in to a string.

Comment: @siva, the services that send push notifications must run on a server. There are lots of services that make this easier, like [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/), [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) and lots more on the [Backend-as-a-service page from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backend_as_a_service)

Comment: is there any procedure with ou this push notifications like using timers or like in android we have broad cast messenger like in ios is there any related to this service which meet my requirement.

Comment: is my reqirement  possible with timers?

Comment: @siva There is an upcoming feature in iOS 7 which allows periodic background time like you're requesting, but nothing in iOS 6 unless you're doing something location-based, VOIP-based, etc. A normal NSTimer will not work in the background. I highly recommend using a server to push for these kinds of notifications.